# VS Code: "Unexpected end of JSON input" error when changing the default org

Tags: vs-code, visualstudiocode

When clicking the "Change Default Org" button in the VS Code status bar, rather than seeing a list of the orgs I was authorised against, I was seeing an error:

```
Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Comment: You can create a brand new SFDX project - this should resolve the issue you have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When checking the JSON files for the authorised orgs (on MacOS, this is in the `~/.sfdx` directory), I noticed one of them was zero bytes. When that was deleted, everything was back working as normal.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue in the sf folder, finding the maxRevision.json file and deleting it.

I then attempted to deploy again and it solved my issue, as well as created a new maxRevision.json folder as welll.

[image]